# Any way to check-in into TFS from FAKE build target?

Tags: tfs, f#, msbuild, f#-fake

I'm trying to create FAKE(F# Make) build target that will update AssemblyInfo files in my project after sucsess build. Version info files are stored in TFS CVS, so I need to checkin updated files to TFS from FAKE build task.

Using TFS 2010, call FAKE from custom activity.

My flow is:
- ... cleanup, call build target
- Update AssemblyInfo files
- Check-in files to TFS

Faced with check-in to TFS issues...

Is there any way to check-in to TFS from FAKE (F# Make) target?

Comment: Why not just use the existing auto-incrementing versioning? If you set the version to something like `Major.Minor.*` (where `Major` and `Minor` are integers), the version will automatically increment.

Comment: @DanielMann Auto-incrementing only works with some versioning schemes. As a counter-example, it doesn't work with Semantic Versioning: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/10/semantic-versioning-with-continuous-deployment

Comment: Currently we don't have TFS helpers directly in FAKE.

Comment: Can you not exec an exe? "tf checkin"

Comment: I've tried to use [SourceLink.Tfs](https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink) module to get TFS API in FAKE script. But "tf checkin" will work for me too. Thanks!

Comment: can you share the build definition template you used to get FAKE running from TFS2010?

Comment: I've attached FMakeTemplate.xaml source in the end of this post: [Run batch file from TFS build](https://vlukashevych.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/run-batch-file-from-tfs-build/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this will come in two parts.  Also, this is working for TFS 2015 new Build Definitions and TFS Git repository.  You can modify this as necessary to fit your particular situation.  These two targets can be called as you wish.

Part I - Update the AssemblyInfo files

```html
let AssemblyInfoFiles = !! @"src\**\AssemblyInfo.cs";
Target "SetVersions" (fun _ ->
  AssemblyInfoFiles
  |> Seq.iter (fun a ->
                  if tfBuildNumber <> null then
                    if isLocalBuild = false then
                      UpdateAttributes a [ Attribute.FileVersion tfBuildNumber]
              )
)
```

Part II - Check in the modified AssemblyInfo file(s)

```html
let CheckInMessage = "Files related to versioning where checked in.  ***NO_CI***"
let tfBuildSourceBranchName =  environVar "BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME"
let tfBuilderRepositoryProvider = environVar "BUILD_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER"
Target "CheckinFiles" (fun _ ->
  AssemblyInfoFiles
  |> Seq.iter (fun a ->
          //This is for GIT REPOSITORY in TFS 2015 Build Definition
          if isLocalBuild = false &&  tfBuilderRepositoryProvider = "TfsGit" then
            checkoutBranch solutionDir tfBuildSourceBranchName
            trace ("File to stage: " + a)
            StageFile solutionDir a |> ignore
            Commit solutionDir CheckInMessage
            pull solutionDir "origin" tfBuildSourceBranchName
            push solutionDir
          )
)
```

The problem with Part II is that it does a commit for EACH AssemblyInfo, whereas I would like to batch these in one single commit.  I can do that, I'm just lazy to fix it.