# How to use F#-Make (FAKE) to override AssemblyInfo.vb when using TFS with exclusive check-out activated?

Tags: vb.net, tfs, f#-fake

I am trying to adopt FAKE in one of our older projects that uses TFS2013 as source control and exclusive check-out as check-out policy. I defined Targets for Clean, Build and RunTests, but I get stuck with the AssemblyInfo-Target. I get the following error (parts of the error message is in german, because I am developing on a german machine):

```
Running build failed.
Error:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Der Zugriff auf den Pfad "D:\SourcecodeTFS2013\AD ERP\AD ERP\ERP.PDFUTILITIES\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" wurde verweigert.
   bei System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   bei System.IO.FileInfo.Delete()
   bei Fake.AssemblyInfoFile.writeToFile(String outputFileName, IEnumerable`1 lines) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\AssemblyInfoFile.fs:Zeile 134.
   bei Fake.AssemblyInfoFile.CreateVisualBasicAssemblyInfoWithConfig(String outputFileName, IEnumerable`1 attributes, AssemblyInfoFileConfig config) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\AssemblyInfoFile.fs:Zeile 233.
   bei FSI_0005.Build.clo@47-2.Invoke(Tuple`4 tupledArg) in D:\SourcecodeTFS2013\AD ERP\AD ERP\build.fsx:Zeile 48.
   bei Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Iterate[T](FSharpFunc`2 action, IEnumerable`1 source)
   bei FSI_0005.Build.clo@27-1.Invoke(Unit _arg2) in D:\SourcecodeTFS2013\AD ERP\AD ERP\build.fsx:Zeile 47.
   bei Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:Zeile 492
```

It seems that this error has to do with the exclusive check-out policy used for this project. That's why the AssemblyInfo.vb file is in “read-only” mode. Is there a possibility in FAKE to do a check-out of the AssemblyInfo.vb before generating the new one?

Here is my "AssemblyInfo"-Target (inspired from the build.fsx script of the Forge project: https://github.com/fsprojects/Forge):

```
Target "AssemblyInfo" (fun _ ->
        let getAssemblyInfoAttributes projectName =
          [ Attribute.Title (projectName)
            Attribute.Product project
            Attribute.Description summary
            Attribute.Company company
            Attribute.CLSCompliant clsCompliant
            Attribute.Version release.AssemblyVersion
            Attribute.FileVersion release.AssemblyVersion ]

        let getProjectDetails projectPath =
          let projectName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(projectPath)
          ( projectPath,
            projectName,
            System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(projectPath),
            (getAssemblyInfoAttributes projectName)
          )

        !! "../**/*.vbproj"
        |> Seq.map getProjectDetails
        |> Seq.iter (fun (projFileName, projectName, folderName, attributes) ->
                      CreateVisualBasicAssemblyInfo ((folderName @@ "My Project") @@ "AssemblyInfo.vb") attributes
                    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something similar for updating packages with Paket:

https://gist.github.com/magicmonty/858066629b08c0e2e310

Have a look at the tfsHelper.fsx

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar: [Any way to check-in into TFS from FAKE build target?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27954563/3452505)

Else you could also change the file attributes before creating assemblyinfo.